# choose appropriate type using template specilization

Tags: c++, templates

Here is the code for templates specilization:

```
template <int i>
struct userInput{};

template <>
struct userInput<1>
{
typedef int typeName;
};

template <>
struct userInput<2>
{
typedef double typeName;
};
```

And I want to choose the appropriate template according to the user input:

```
int i;
std::cin>>i;
userInput<i>::typeName ty;
```

But the compiler is not happy with me, it requires a contant value to be passed in to the template parameter.
So I did this:

```
int i;
std::cin>>i;    
const int p = i;
userInput<p>::typeName ty;
```

However, there is error :template parameter 'i' : 'num' : a local variable cannot be used as a non-type argument. Anyone can help me out? I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to `switch` on the input to find the constant value to feed to your template.

```
template <int i>
void foo () {
    typename userInput<i>::typeName ty = 1;
    std::cout << ty/2 << std::endl;
}

int i;
std::cin >> i;
switch (i) {
case 1:  foo<1>(); break;
case 2:  foo<2>(); break;
default: std::cerr << "invalid type: " << i << std::endl;
}
```

So, if the input is `1`, the output is `0`. If the input is `2`, the output is `0.5`. For others, the error message appears.

The difference between the code in `foo`, and the code you tried to write is that `foo<1>` and `foo<2>` are two different functions, each with a different `ty` variable, and each `ty` variable has a different type. In contrast, your code has a single `ty` variable that tries to be both kinds of `typeName`s at the same time, sort of like Schroedinger's Cat. The compiler failed to collapse the waveform, so it complained.

Comment: This is basically the same as `template<class T> void foo() {}`, and using a different T for every input: `case 1: foo<int>();`, but a lot longer since you need the `userInput` trait which serves no purpose in your code.

Comment: @mfontanini: I did it this way to let the `foo` function look like the code the OP put down in the question. Thanks and regards

Comment: @user315052    As you wrote in the above, 'foo<1>','foo<2>' are two different functions with their own type member. However, what if I want to extract the type stored in the 'foo' and use it to define variables? I think this gonna be a problem, 'cause outside the switch loop, you have no access to the 'userInput::typeName'.

Comment: @Gao: You can just write the code you want to write in `foo` itself, if I understand your question correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Non-type template parameters require constant compile-time expressions, since they are instantiated during compilation:

```
const int x = 1;
int y = 1;
userInput<x>::typeName a; // valid
userInput<1>::typeName a; // valid
userInput<y>::typeName b; // invalid, what should be instantiated?
```

There is no way to achieve what you want to do, since the `p` constant will be initialized during runtime.

Answer (score 1):

As mfontanini explains (and your compiler complains), non-type template parameters have to be compile-time constants. And your attempt to fool it by "const int p = i;" doesn't help; p may be constant variable, but it's not a compile-time constant. A C++11 compiler can do a better job telling you what's wrong here, but it can't help you get around the problem. In fact, there is no direct way around the problem.

The simplest solution is an explicit switch, as user315052 suggests. And, if you're only doing this once, and just switching on 1 vs. 2, it's not worth putting in more effort than that.

If you're doing the switch lots of times, of course, it's trivial to wrap it in a function:

```
void bar(int i) {
  switch(i) {
  case 1: foo(userInput<1>::typeName()); return;
  case 2: foo(userInput<2>::typeName()); return;
  default: throw someException;
}
```

But if you have a lot more than 2 cases, or the set of values is in constant flux, you'll definitely want to use Boost.Preprocessor to automate the cruft, which would look something like this:

```
#define FOO_CASES_ 50
#define FOO_PASTE_(rep, i, _) case i: foo(userInput< i >::typeName()); return;
void bar(int i) {
  switch (i) {
    BOOST_PP_REPEAT(FOO_CASES_, FOO_PASTE_, _)
    default: throw someException;
  }
}
#undef FOO_CASES_
#undef FOO_PASTE_
```

Or, alternatively, write a code generator that creates a .cpp file for you to compile:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
with file('bar.cpp', 'w') as f:
  f.write('void bar(int i) {\n')
  f.write('  switch(i) {\n')
  for i in range(50):
    f.write('    case %d: foo(userInput<%d>::typeName()); return;\n' % (i, i))
  f.write('  default: throw someException;\n')
  f.write('  }\n')
  f.write('}\n')
```

Yet another alternative is to create a lookup array (or vector) that's initialized with the appropriate objects/functions/whatever, so you can use *userInputLookup[i] in place of userInput. But without knowing the exact use case, and whether you're using C++11, it's hard to give details.